# XCode Polygon Sprite Problems

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am using the code below to try and generate a polygon shape sprite.  I am running into problems with the code, can anyone spot anything wrong with it?

```
   b2BodyDef woodBodyDef;
     woodBodyDef.position.Set(400/PTM_RATIO,100/PTM_RATIO);
     woodBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
     woodBodyDef.userData = _wood;
     _body = _world->CreateBody(&woodBodyDef);

     b2PolygonShape woodShape;

     int num = 4;
     b2Vec2 vertices[] = {
     b2Vec2(-137.0f/PTM_RATIO,-32.5f/PTM_RATIO),
     b2Vec2(-137.0f /PTM_RATIO,36.5f/PTM_RATIO),
     b2Vec2(137.0f /PTM_RATIO,36.5f/PTM_RATIO),
     b2Vec2(136.0f /PTM_RATIO, -32.5f/PTM_RATIO)
     };
     woodShape.Set(vertices, num);



     b2FixtureDef woodShapeDef;
     woodShapeDef.shape = &woodShape;
     woodShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
     woodShapeDef.friction = 1.0f;
     woodShapeDef.restitution = 0.5f;
     woodBodyDef.userData = _wood;
     _body = _world->CreateBody(&woodBodyDef);
```

Comment: Can you share the errors (if any) that occur, or what happens when this runs?  Does it just do nothing?  Does something appear that isn't desired?  Can you provide a little more info about what exactly happens with this.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=608369395847146&set=a.198688853481871.58423.100000222736877&type=1&theater   this it problem pic when i run

Comment: @AlexSmith That's box2d code, not his. Also it says b2Assert(area > b2_epsilon);

Comment: Oops! Thanks @Sebastian ; ) Removed comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that the order of vertices matters. You define them in clockwise order, Box2D might expect them to be in counter-clockwise order. It's easy to verify so just give it a try and see if that fixes the assert (which btw says that the polygon area is <= 0).

Comment: thank a lot of your comment  ,i understand today  ,thank you  .  :)